# Find a $1-1$ function mapping the interval $(0,1)$ to the set of rational numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Written another way, $f : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f$ is a bijection.  I can't think of a function capable of this.  If I just map the input to the same output value the function will never reach values outside of $(0,1)$.  Am I looking at this the wrong way or is there a flaw in my understanding of a $1$-$1$ correspondence?

Comment: Are you familiar with the $\tan$ function from trigonometry?

Comment: And of course, we have that $\Bbb Q\subsetneq \Bbb R$...

Comment: The title of your question says "rational" but the text of the question has the standard symbol $\mathbb R$ for the set of *real* numbers. Did you mean $\mathbb Q$, the set of rational numbers, or did you mean the set of real numbers?

Comment: Apologies, I did mean real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it
because the rationals are countable
and the interval is uncountable.

Comment: A one-way function (onto?) is possible, such that we have $f:(0,1)\to\Bbb Q$, but of course it cannot be a bijection...

Comment: If I looked at it from that perspective initially it would've made a lot more sense to me.  Thanks for the concise and clear explanation.